# actionscript 3.0 visible mask over a visible masked object

Tags: actionscript-3, mask

I have a moving truck in my game and I want the city lights reflections (NOT the background) to be visible over its body as it moves around.

What stands behind the truck does not matter, some trees and buildings.

So,
I add the background (not important);
then I add the truck to the stage;
then I add another MovieClip with the size of the whole stage (city lights and stuff) and I set it as a masking object for my truck.

I dont want the truck to disappear, i just want the masking object show up over it with some transparency;

I know about masking and also catching my movieclips as bitmaps but it wont work in my case; because here the truck stays totally visible and the mask semi-transparent.

Please help me, I'm running out of time:/

**EDIT**

Here is my current code based off one of the asnwers:

```
var buildingHolder: Sprite = new Sprite;
this.addChild(buildingHolder);

var Mask: Sprite = new Sprite()
Mask = Sprite(buildingHolder);
Mask.alpha = 1;
Mask.cacheAsBitmap = true;
this.addChild(Mask);

var reflection: MovieClip = new nightSky1Mask;
reflection.x = 0;
reflection.y = 480;
reflection.alpha = .6;
reflection.scaleX *= 320 / reflection.width;
reflection.scaleY = reflection.scaleX;
reflection.cacheAsBitmap = true;
reflection.mask = Mask;
this.addChild(reflection);

for (var i: int = 0; i <= 29; i++){
//some codes are deleted here

    var image: MovieClip = new level1Images[i];
    image.x = // deleted
    image.y = // deleted
    image.scaleX *= 30 / image.width * 2;
    image.scaleY *= 5 / image.width * 2;
    buildingHolder.addChild(image)
    currLevelImages.push(image)
}
```

Comment: Show your current code.     You need to create a mask for the city lights MovieClip  because you don't want to mask the truck, you want to mask the lights.  If your truck is a png or bimtap type object with transparency, it's pretty easy to create a copy that can be your mask for the lights.  If you show your code, a specific example can be given.

Comment: I think the problem here is that this Mask is the buildingHolder itself, I mean when i set its alpha to 0.1 I cannot see the buildingHolder behind it. They are exactly the same not copies! @LDMS

Comment: Yes,  casting an object doesn't copy it.  What you are doing is creating a new sprite (in the Mask var), then right after that assigning the var the same object that is in the buildingHolder var.  One object, two vars referencing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **DON'T** want to mask the truck.  What you want to mask are the city lights.

You need to create a copy of the truck, and mask the city lights with that.

Assuming you have a Bitmap in your library with exported class as `TruckImage` and your lights are exported for actionscript as `Lights`, you can do something like this:

```
var truck:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new TruckImage());

//scale and position however you'd like
truck.scaleX = truck.scaleY = .25;
truck.y = 100;
addChild(truck);    

var theMask:Bitmap = new Bitmap(truck.bitmapData);
theMask.cacheAsBitmap = true;//!very important
theMask.scaleX = theMask.scaleY = truck.scaleX;
addChild(theMask); //also important

lights = new Bitmap(new Lights());
lights.cacheAsBitmap = true;//!very important
lights.mask = theMask;
addChild(lights);

//let's move the truck and the mask every frame
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrame);
function enterFrame(e:Event):void {
    truck.x = (truck.x + 2) % stage.stageWidth;
    theMask.x = truck.x;
}
```

**EDIT**

Try something like this: (creating a bitmap copy of your building)

```
    var buildingHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();
    this.addChild(buildingHolder);

    //create a bitmap data object and draw the building holder sprite into it (making a copy)
    var maskBMD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(buildingHolder.width,buildingHolder.height,true,0x00000000);
    maskBMD.draw(buildingHolder);

    var msk:Bitmap = new Bitmap(maskBMD,"auto",true);
    msk.cacheAsBitmap = true;
    this.addChild(msk);

    var reflection:MovieClip = new nightSky1Mask;
    reflection.x = 0;
    reflection.y = 480;
    reflection.alpha = .6;
    reflection.scaleX *= 320 / reflection.width;
    reflection.scaleY = reflection.scaleX;
    reflection.cacheAsBitmap = true;
    reflection.mask = msk;
    this.addChild(reflection);

    for (var i: int = 0; i <= 29; i++){
    //some codes are deleted here

        var image: MovieClip = new level1Images[i];
        image.x = // deleted
        image.y = // deleted
        image.scaleX *= 30 / image.width * 2;
        image.scaleY *= 5 / image.width * 2;
        buildingHolder.addChild(image)
        currLevelImages.push(image)
    }
```

---

Or, you could do something like this to make two copies of your building:

```
    var buildingHolder:Sprite = createBuilding();
    var buildingHolderMask:Sprite = createBuilding(false);

    function createBuilding(addToArray:Boolean = true):Sprite {
        var building:Sprite = new Sprite();

        for (var i: int = 0; i <= 29; i++){
        //some codes are deleted here

            var image: MovieClip = new level1Images[i];
            image.x = // deleted
            image.y = // deleted
            image.scaleX *= 30 / image.width * 2;
            image.scaleY *= 5 / image.width * 2;
            building.addChild(image)
            if(addToArray) currLevelImages.push(image)
        }
        return building;
    }
```

Comment: I am so thankful;
Unfortunately I absolutely cannot show the code, for guessable reasons!
If you want the truth there is no truck at all, there are series of movieclips (parts of a building) moving on the basis of a physics engine.
they are all added to a single sprite called buildingHolder.
As the building parts are moving and shaking around, the lights of the city must be visible on this building (which has glazing) to make the feeling of reflection.

I'm gonna try and see if your code will work in my case and will update you.
Thanks again

Comment: Ok the first issue i just faced is that as i said all those parts are in a single sprite, so for example mySprite.bitmapData will not work.    
How can I make a copy of a Sprite with all its children inside moving around as a bitmapData?

Comment: How do you instantiate said sprite?  Is it through code or by dropping it on the timeline?

Comment: It is through code. But now it doesn't matter because I made the mask as a copy of my building holder and the reflections are now masking my Mask; It's all as you said and it is masked perfectly but there is another issue; the building itself is not visible any more. I only the the lights(reflections).
I'm gonna write some code below but dont know how to code in format here! how do you do it?

Comment: wrap code in backticks `  (same key as tilda ~).   Yeah, if doing through code you can just instantiate another copy and use that as the mask - basically the same as my example only with your Sprite instead of bitmap data).  You probably just need to set an alpha on your reflection. `lights.alpha = .2` or there abouts

Comment: I missed the word "see", so I only see the lights over the building but my building is not visible! I tried changing the alpha of my mask and masked but it wont help and instead it just maked the whole building semi-transparent!

Comment: what is that c ? c.mask = msk

Comment: Sorry, when I was testing my equivalent of your reflections was called `c`.  I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working. I used your second method coz the first one didn't work (creating a bitmap copy of my building returns a bunch of errors). Now I just need to manipulate the graphics. LDMS can I somehow have your personal contact? email?

Comment: Glad you got it working.  I don't give out my contact information publicly. Feel free to ask another question on SO though, there a lots of people to help in this community